# Returning values through VLookUp in sequence of Multiple Instances

Tags: excel, vba, macos

This is my first question in this forum.. 
I am facing problem in excel macro. I have two different workbook. I have to pick particular values from first workbook and copy in another workbook according to match.

1st Workbook:

```
coffee yes
tea    no
coffee yes
coffee no
coffee no
tea    yes
tea    no
tea    yes
tea    no
```

2nd workbook:

```
coffee
milk
tea
coffee
coffee
milk
coffee
tea
tea
tea
tea
```

Result File

```
coffee yes
milk   yes
tea    no
coffee yes
coffee no
milk   yes
coffee no
tea    yes
tea    no
tea    yes
tea    no
```

In this I want corresponding value of coffee or tea from first workbook to second workbook.
I use following formula for this

`=VLOOKUP(D:D,'source.xlsx]Tab1'!$D:$E,2,0)`

By using this formula it only return "yes" value for coffee everytime. 
Can anyone help in this regard?
Thanks in advance.
 M@c

Comment: So you want the *nth* match?  I believe you will need a combination of COUNTIF, VLOOKUP, and an Array.  Also, where are the values for *milk* to come from?

Comment: @Joe No Array needed if you use a helper column =)

Comment: @joe: milk column will be filled by user.

Comment: @user2140261 : i dont want helper column as i need to use this sheet for official purpose so my tool will automatically send it after this result.

Comment: are you sending the entire workbook or only the result sheet?

Comment: i m sending only the result sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option Does require an added Column on each sheet BUT the Column can be hidden.

on Sheet one Column C add this formula starting at Row 1

```
=A1&" "&COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)
```

Notice the `$`'s and where they are this is locking specific values in while allowing the correct values to change as you drag this formula down.

[image]

Next on sheet 2 enter the SAME formula in Column B.

But also on Sheet2 you will need the lookup formula below:

```
=INDEX(LookUpTable!B:B,MATCH(LookUpValues!B1,LookUpTable!C:C,0))
```

and this will result as so:

[image]

Comment: +1 I agree that a helper column is a great way to go. You could pretty easily get rid of it on the main sheet (Sheet 1) by concatenating the column A name and the `COUNTIF` result into the `MATCH` function.